# How to get the average of a column that is connected to a datetime column in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, iis, cgi

Hello I am trying to get the average of column tc that has a specific date as well as getting its another average in each different date only. Is there a mysql query for it? Here is my weatherdata table:

[tc is 31 date is 2022-03-11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrYpx.png)

[tc is 35 date is 2022-03-13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqAza.png)

[tc is 41 date is 2022-03-14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP8oA.png)

[tc is 100 date is 2022-03-15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sGZc.png)

### My current try of mysqlquery is this

```
select round(avg(tc),0),date_format(dtime,'%m/%d/%Y') as timeee from weatherdata where DATE(dtime) BETWEEN '2022-03-13' AND '2022-03-15';
```

I am trying to achieve this one using Python and Matplotlib wherein the dates in mysql is shown in the x axis of the graph and the y values that are plotted are the average of column tc in each different date.

[trying to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjbP0.png)

Hopefully someone can help me please thanks. Still learning

Comment: `union` two `selects` together one of each average.

Comment: How is that @JonSG

Comment: please show your data as text instead of images.  output of `show create table weatherdata;` would also be helpful.

Comment: it isn't clear to me what you are asking for.  please show what results you want from your query for the data you show.

Comment: data in table weatherdata is too long @ysth

Comment: I want an average of column tc in each different date

Comment: What sql result do you want. Let's start there before jumping to visualizations. Are you maybe looking to include a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: you will get much better help if you can show (all as text, not images) your schema, sample data, and your expected results for that sample data (not a description of the results, or a graph produced from the results, but the actual desired results from a query)

Comment: what's most confusing to me, and maybe other people too, is your "as well as"; it sounds like you are asking for two different things, one of which is an average for each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound to me like you want to have an average for each day.  You probably want to use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(dtime,'%m/%d/%Y') as timeee,
  ROUND(AVG(tc),0)
FROM
    weatherdata
WHERE
    DATE(dtime) BETWEEN '2022-03-13' AND '2022-03-15'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY DATE(dtime);
```

Comment: I'll try this one and update you if it works

Comment: you probably want to order by DATE(dtime), not the formatted date

Comment: true enough  as I see the value is not y-m-d.

Comment: Hey @JonSG your code worked! Thank you so much! It saved me time from browsing the internet for answer.

Comment: Thanks also @ysth for clarifications and trying to help, muchly appreciated.